# Magento - Google chrome sets new session - unable to login as customer

Tags: magento, google-chrome

I'am not at the point where my hair starts to turn gray..

Two sessions is created by magento, this seems to be right, works in IE/FF:

```
PHPSESSID
hqndmkildduflb04lpgohu6pk5
www.domain.com
/
Tue, 12 Mar 2013 11:31:57 GMT
35
PHPSESSID
hqndmkildduflb04lpgohu6pk5
.www.domain.com
/
Tue, 12 Mar 2013 11:31:56 GMT
```

The strange thing is, when logging out and closing the browser, reopen and go to the login site again, another session is now created, and I'm now unable to log in:

```
PHPSESSID
ru9lvno0mt8kpj6lhb2g3vmlq3
.domain.com
/
Tue, 12 Mar 2013 11:42:51 GMT
35
```

When deleting the 3 sessions, I can login again, creating two new sessions. This only happens in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that it actually has something to do with cookies. 
In System->Config->Web->SessionCookieManagement try setting the path to '' (empty), domain to 'domain.com', use HTTP only to 'YES', and Cookie Restriction Mode to 'NO'.

Comment: It worked! Now there's only 1 session, and it seems to have fixed my problem. Thank you